# Automatically update data in sql for a webpage

Tags: php, sql, web

So I'm a software Development student and for my web class I created a project that uses among other things Php and SQL; In this project, users can create posts and other users can comment on them.

The thing is I want posts to only be available for a certain period of time.

Then I have an SQL table named **'Posts'** and they have a column named **'Status'** (you know, if the status it's 0 they're not available and else they are.)

When a user creates a post I make SQL: 
`INSERT INTO posts *All the post data*`, I set the Status to 1 and make a `TIMESTAMP` to register the date of creation of the post. I want that a week after the date registered in the Timestamp changes the status column to 0 but I don't want it to be with a page request (I need it to be automatic) and I want the user to be notified via email or something.

Can it be made with some python CGI that checks the date, updates the Status and sends the email or is there a better/easier way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the best way to solve this was using [Cron Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

I run a PHP script every day and I modify the posts which are exactly 7 days old, using

```
UPDATE Posts SET Status = 0 WHERE DATE(timestamp_col) = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

And then I iterate through the affected rows emailing the users.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the `status` 0/1 AND the `timestamp` column, if all you want to do is show a post for a set period of time.

Just use the `timestamp` column and amend the queries that fetch the posts to only show those posts that are < 7 days old (or any period you decide)

EG

```
SELECT * from posts where timestamp_col < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

or something similiar that meets your needs

Comment: It would workfor the page display but not for the user notification

Comment: Sure it would just add a `user_emailed` column and set that when you send a user notification, and dont select them again is `user_email = 1`